# How to set screen brightness per application in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, brightness, intellij-idea

I hop between my browser and a few applications, and only one (an IDE) is dark-themed; for optimal viewing, I raise brightness on the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) - but that makes every other application too bright.

This said, is there a method in Windows (built-in or via software) to automatically change screen brightness when tabbing to a specific program? Alternatively, an IntelliJ config?

---

- **System info**: Win-10 Home, ASUS ROG Strix [GL702VSK](https://amzn.to/2TAedUh)
- **AHK version**: 1.1.29.01
- **DDC/CI**: unsure if supported, but laptop model is fairly recent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the free script language [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
together with the free monitor-control
[ControlMyMonitor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html).

The following example script will dim the screen to 50% when the title of
the active window contains the string "Untitled - Notepad", and return it
to 100% when the window loses the focus:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2       ; set title substring match
dimmed := 0
Loop
{
    sleep 500  # run loop every 500ms
    IfWinActive, Untitled - Notepad
    {
        if (dimmed = 0)
        {
            dimmed = 1
            Run, ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue Primary 10 50
        }
    } else {
        if (dimmed = 1)
        {
            dimmed = 0
            Run, ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue Primary 10 100
        }
    }
}
```

This script assumes that the script and `ControlMyMonitor` are in the same
folder. If that's not the case, add its path to the command.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

An alternative if `ControlMyMonitor` does not work for your computer is
[ClickMonitorDDC](https://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net/)
which uses other Windows API.

Sample code to set brightness to 50%:

```
Run, ClickMonitorDDC_7_0.exe b 50`
```

[AutoHotKey IfWinActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm)
can be added for a filename-agnostic check.
For example checking for `IntelliJ IDEA` project names:

```
IfWinActive, IntelliJ IDEA
```

Comment: `ControlMyMonitor` appears to fail, question updated w/ details -- any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't fail in my tests. Try just running in CMD the command `"C:\path\ControlMyMonitor.exe /SetValue Primary 10 50`.

Comment: Does nothing, but removing any commands (`/SetValue ...`), it launches the `.exe`; it also does nothing for `Action` from within `.exe` - increase/decrease value; an alternative to ControlMyMonitor, perhaps?

Comment: Sure it's not the antivirus blocking? You may find more products [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/clickmonitorddc/), but I don't know which ones have command-line support. I only tested ClickMonitorDDC, and it too worked for me.

Comment: Excellent, ClickMonitorDDC worked; accept my edit or make your own so I can accept the answer. Also, your solution is exactly what I had in mind, was just lacking the "change brightness" step. -- Thanks